# how to add a new line to only the end of the output sequence

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int num1;

 int num2;

 int i;
 
 scanf("%d", &num1);
  scanf("%d", &num2);
 
if (num1 <= num2) {
   for(i = num1; i <= num2; i +=5 ){
   
   printf("%d \n",i);
  
   
   
   }
}
   
   else {
   
   printf("Second integer can't be less than the first.\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to only add one new line to the end of the outputs but every time I execute this program it adds several new lines to the end of each output and I only need one at the very last output.
for example, if I input `-15 10` then I will get an output of

```
  -15 
-10 
-5 
0 
5 
10
```

when I'm only looking for one new line at the end of the `10`
I want my output to look like this with only one new line at the end.

```
-15 -10 -5 0 5 10 \n
```

Comment: Do you know what the `\n` in the `printf` statement does?

Comment: Remove the `'\n'` from the `printf()` inside the loop, and print a single `'\n'` _after_ the loop.  Forgive for not posting that as an answer, but it seems so clearly obvious, I wonder if I am missing something?

Comment: `for(i = num1; i <= num2; i +=5 ) printf (i != num1 ? " %d" : "%d", i); putchar ('\n');` is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Print your newline outside of the for loop. This way you can print all your numbers, then when finished put a new line on the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int num1;
  int num2;
  int i;
 
  scanf("%d", &num1);
  scanf("%d", &num2);
 
  if (num1 <= num2) {
    for(i = num1; i <= num2; i +=5 ){
      printf("%d ",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
  } else {
    printf("Second integer can't be less than the first.\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include `\n` inside the loop. Print it when the loop is done.

```
for(i = num1; i <= num2; i +=5 ){
   printf("%d ",i);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: I'd do the final with `putchar('\n');` -- (of course I'd have to dump the assembly to see if `printf ("\n");` was already optimized that way)

Comment: I considered it, decided not to introduce a new concept. I would bet anything it's optimized like that.

Comment: I bet you are right. Optimizations have gotten much better with `printf()` and just a literal. (I'll try later, if anything significant, I'll drop a comment -- doubt there will be)

Answer (score 1):

Scince the obvious answer is, well... obvious, and also well covered by other answers, consider this alternative;

```
for( i = num1; i <= num2; i += 5 )
{
    printf( "%d%c", i,
            i + 5 > num2 ? '\n' : 
                           ' ' ) ;
}
```

It is somewhat more complicated, but does not print a trailing space in the line.

The expression `i + 5 > num2` is a test to determine whether the loop will terminate after `i += 5`.  However you would do well to define a symbolic constant for that so that given, say:

```
#define STEP 5
```

then:

```
for( i = num1; i <= num2; i += STEP )
{
    printf( "%d%c", i,
            i + STEP > num2 ? '\n' : 
                              ' ' ) ;
}
```

It can be simplified a little with a while loop:

```
i = num1 ;
while( i <= num2 )
{
    printf( "%d", i ) ;
    i += STEP ;
    printf( "%c", i > num2 ? '\n' : 
                             ' ' ) ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your point. Yes - spotted that while adding to the answer and after posting the comment.  That is what comes from trying to type code on a phone!  It was not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

You *really* need to pay attention to the formatting of your code. LOTS of bugs hide in poorly formatted code, and code that uses more variables and statements than are needed, and code that does not validate user data before using it.

Here's a version that is direct and to the point:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mmain() {
    int n1, n2; // short names; easy to type and to read.

    // Get two integers (without a prompt)
    if( scanf( "%d%d", &n1, &n2 ) != 2 || n1 > n2 ) {
        printf( "Bad data. Second integer must be greater than first.\n" );
        return 1; // early termination as execution cannot continue.
    }

    // loop, printing values, each with appropriate next character (SP or LF)
    do
        printf( "%d%c", n1, " \n"[n1+5>n2] );
    while( (n1+=5) <= n2 );

    return 0;
}
```